# How do you set up an API Gateway Step Function integration using Terraform and aws_apigatewayv2_integration

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am looking for an example on how to start execution of a step function from API Gateway using Terraform and the `aws_apigatewayv2_integration` resource. I am using an HTTP API (have only found an older example for REST API's on Stackoverflow).

Currently I have this:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "workflow_proxy_integration" {
  api_id                  = aws_apigatewayv2_api.default.id
  credentials_arn         = aws_iam_role.api_gateway_step_functions.arn
  integration_type        = "AWS_PROXY"
  integration_subtype     = "StepFunctions-StartExecution"
  description             = "The integration which will start the Step Functions workflow."
  payload_format_version  = "1.0"

  request_parameters = {
    StateMachineArn = aws_sfn_state_machine.default.arn
  }
}
```

Right now, my State Machine receives an empty input (`"input": {}`). When I try to add `input` to the `request_parameters` section, I get this error:

> Error: error updating API Gateway v2 integration: BadRequestException: Parameter: input does not fit schema for Operation: StepFunctions-StartExecution.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue trying to pass the request body into the step function as input

Answer (score 1):

I spent over an hour looking for a solution to a similar problem I was having with `request_parameters`. AWS's documentation currently uses camelCase for their keys in all of their examples (`stateMachineArn`, `input`, etc.) so it made it difficult to research.

You'll want to use PascalCase for your keys, similar to how you already did for `StateMachineArn`. So instead of `input`, you'll use `Input`.